# how to set default media (paper size) for a printer using lpoptions

Tags: printing, media, cups-lpd

I want lp to print to a default printer and can set this using lpoptions -d ,
but I can't find a way to set the default media size. Is there any way to do this with some lp... command or do I need to edit some config file?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If you are not using Ubuntu indicate the distro of Linux as well. Please provide all these information by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1354384/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose DESTINATION is the name of a print queue (as shown, for example, in a print dialog). Obtain a list of printer specific options and their current settings with `lpoptions -p DESTINATION -l`. It will contain a section for `PageSize`.

Let's say you want A4 as the default media size. Do `lpoptions -p DESTINATION -o PageSize=A4`.

For additional information read the manual for lpoptions:

```
man lpoptions
```

Comment: You may also use the `papersize` command. See `man papersize`.

Comment: The `papersize` command affects _all_ printers and also requires root privileges. Changing PageSize on a job-by-job basis is easily done with `lp -p DESTINATION -o PageSize JOB`.

Comment: there is typo : `lpoptions -p DESTINATION -o PageSize=A4`

Answer (score 0):

Just an update you can change the page size on default for all the printers by going to /etc/papersize